# Disabling form element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use jquery to disable a form element once a check box is clicked, however it doesnt seem to be working. Can anyone see whats wrong?

```
$('name="globallyAddTime"').click(function() {
if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
       $('name="addedQuantity[]"').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('name="addedQuantity[]"').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pocockn/bwmv7/4/

Comment: also your fiddle doesn't have jQuery Framework

Comment: use .prop('disabled', true)/.prop('disabled', false) instead of attr/removeAttr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute selector should be like this [`[attr=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[name="globallyAddTime"]').change(function() {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
       $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bwmv7/10/)

You can make it simplified as follows

```
$('[name="globallyAddTime"]').change(function() {
     $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/bwmv7/13/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (use prop instead attr)

```
$('name="globallyAddTime"').click(function() {
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
       $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

attr don't return current state of checkbox.

And you have an error in name selector. Need `[name="addedQuantity[]"]`

Comment: Also [name="globallyAddTime"] for the input checkbox.

Comment: For jQuery 1.6+, use `prop` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 1):

When selecting an attribute, you have to use []:

```
$('[name="globallyAddTime"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('[name="addedQuantity[]"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('[name="globallyAddTime"]').click(function() {
     if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
         $('#addedQuantiy_1').attr('disabled', true);
     } else {
         $('#addedQuantiy_1').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwmv7/11/)**

Answer (score 0):

**I got it.**

```
<div id="addIngredient">
                        <p>
                            <input type="text" id="ingredient_1" name="ingredient[]" value="" placeholder="Ingredient" />
                            <input type="text" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity" />
                            <select id="selectQuantity_1" name="quantityType[]">
                                <option value="grams">Grams</option>
                                <option value="ounces">Ounces</option>
                                <option value="Pounds">Pounds</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="text" id="alternative_1" name="alternative[]" value="" placeholder="Alternative Ingredient" />
                            <input type="text" id="addedQuantiy_1" name="addedQuantity" value="" placeholder="Quantity per extra person" />

                            <a href="#" id="addNewIngredient">Add Ingredient</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>


<h2>Added Time</h2>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="globallyAddTime" id="global" value="Global" />
                    <label>Increase Quantites Proportionally to Portion Number</label>
                </div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#global').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
           $('input[name=addedQuantity]').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        inputs.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: by the way. maybe you can avoid using `[]` in your input name. it wouldn't hurt you anyway. ^_^